# Angularjs $http not returning object on promise

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sharepoint-2013, angular-material

I am working with angularjs with angular material but it is not returning object from $http my full code pen is at http://codepen.io/milindsaraswala/pen/rLjLMX

```
<md-autocomplete md-input-name="autocompleteField" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
                                                                 md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="0"
                                                                 md-floating-label="Station" flex required>
                                    <md-item-template>
                                        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
                                    </md-item-template>
                                    <div ng-messages="searchForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="searchForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
                                        <div ng-message="required">You <b>must</b> have a favorite state.</div>
                                        <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
                                        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </md-autocomplete>
```

What I am doing wrong !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `loadAll()` needs to return a promise.

```
    function loadAll() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var url = "http://webdev.kuwaitairways.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('KAC_Stations')/items?$select=Id,City_Code,City_Name_EN&$filter=Active eq 1&$orderby=City_Name_EN asc";
  $timeout(function() {
    httpGetService.getDataItem(url).then(function(result) {
      var allStations = [];
      angular.forEach(result, function(b) {
        var station = {
          value: b.City_Code.toLowerCase(),
          display: b.City_Name_EN + '(' + b.City_Code + ')'
        }
        allStations.push(station);
      });
      deferred.resolve(allStations);
    }, function(err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    })
  }, 1000);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Here is the working example. http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/XKpRaP

Comment: Thanks, It is working as needed but page become very heavy and hanging. Other thing in console I am getting error **Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress** What can be the reason

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening.  take a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog